# Parsing a Nested JSON output

Tags: java, android, json

**What i am doing**::`I have a Json Structure` I want to extract `Bangalore` having key `adminArea5`

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "latLng": {
                        "lng": 77.620949,
                        "lat": 12.931088
                    },
                    "adminArea4": "Bangalore Urban",
                    "adminArea5Type": "City",
                    "adminArea4Type": "County",
                    "adminArea5": "Bangalore",
                    "street": "Sarjapur Road",
                    "adminArea1": "IN",
                    "adminArea3": "Karnataka",
                    "type": "s",
                    "displayLatLng": {
                        "lng": 77.617502,
                        "lat": 12.928883
                    },
                    "linkId": 0,
                    "postalCode": "560095",
                    "sideOfStreet": "N",
                    "dragPoint": false,
                    "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                    "geocodeQuality": "ADDRESS",
                    "geocodeQualityCode": "L1AAA",
                    "mapUrl": "http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luur2d0821,8s=o5-9arwha&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,12.931088,77.620949,0,0|&center=12.931088,77.620949&zoom=15&rand=981886032",
                    "adminArea3Type": "State"
                }
            ],
            "providedLocation": {
                "latLng": {
                    "lng": 77.620949,
                    "lat": 12.931088
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "ignoreLatLngInput": false,
        "maxResults": -1,
        "thumbMaps": true
    },
    "info": {
        "copyright": {
            "text": "© 2014 MapQuest, Inc.",
            "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
            "imageAltText": "© 2014 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
        "statuscode": 0,
        "messages": []
    }
}
```

`What i have done so far`::

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(Content);   
                Log.d("Content", Content.toString());
                myString=jsonobject.getString("results").toString();
```

**With the code above** :: `I have the JSON Structure`

```
[
    {
        "providedLocation": {
            "latLng": {
                "lat": 12.931088,
                "lng": 77.620949
            }
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 12.931088,
                    "lng": 77.620949
                },
                "adminArea5Type": "City",
                "adminArea4": "Bangalore Urban",
                "adminArea5": "Bangalore",
                "adminArea4Type": "County",
                "street": "Sarjapur Road",
                "adminArea1": "IN",
                "adminArea3": "Karnataka",
                "type": "s",
                "displayLatLng": {
                    "lat": 12.928883,
                    "lng": 77.617502
                },
                "linkId": 0,
                "postalCode": "560095",
                "dragPoint": false,
                "sideOfStreet": "N",
                "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                "geocodeQuality": "ADDRESS",
                "geocodeQualityCode": "L1AAA",
                "adminArea3Type": "State",
                "mapUrl": "http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luur2d0821,8s=o5-9arwha&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,12.931088,77.620949,0,0|&center=12.931088,77.620949&zoom=15&rand=-1939275403"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Question**:: How to get `Bangalore` having key `adminArea5`

Comment: -1, shows no research effort.  Read about [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: Guess ...if a person gets one downvode ... others simply downvote !(they won't even read also i guess) ... this is bad ... this question looks a valid one to me ... as backward compatibility for handling certain JSON structure is a good info in the site ... ill try to improve my explanation standards in the further posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you've an `JSONArray()` within your `JSONObject`.

Try to get the JSONOBject result, pick out the

`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.get("results"))`.

In your JSONArray you can parse out your required data.

Comment: Sounds good approach ... since im using android i have a warning call requires API-19 .... is it possible to use another approach ?

Comment: It does not require API-19. It depends on your JSON Library. Use a library which can handle this.

Comment: Cool [+1] for i/p ...can you recommend a good library i can use ... from that point i think i can resolve this

Comment: I prefer using Gson, but it's not a lightweight library. It depends what you are actually trying todo. If you want to serialize it back to an classobject it's good.

Comment: I was not trying to use a Class object .... prefer parsing directly .... any third party libraries i can use other than GSON ?

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

its the same which is already implemented in API 19. Just grab the source or the library then old versions can handle this